# Laravel error Unauthenticated when passing Datatable from view to controller

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel-5, datatables

Hello i'm trying to pass Datatable from view to my controller. Here is my Datatable code in view :

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-hover display">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th><input type="checkbox" name="select_all" value="1" id="example-select-all" /></th>
        <th>No</th>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Exemplar</th>
        <th width="40%">Title</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="bookTable"></tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

And here is my javascript code :

```
$('#printLabel').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post("{{ url('admin/printselectedlabel') }}",
        //$('#searchForm').serialize())
        table1.$('input,select,textarea').serialize()).fail(function(data) {
        alert(data.responseJSON.error);
    });
});
```

The codes above gave me error : {error: "Unauthenticated."}. Also, i'm not sure if "table1.$('input,select,textarea').serialize())" is the right why to pass datatable to controller.

Here is my route :

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function () {

Route::post('/printselectedlabel',           'Admin\PrintLabelController@printSelectedLabel');});
```

I havent add any code yet inside the printSelectedLabel() function inside the PrintLabelController

```
 public function __construct()
{
     $this->middleware('admin'); 
}public function printSelectedLabel(Request $request){

}
```

Comment: Is your route for admin/printselectedlabel protected by some sort of middleware?

Comment: show your route and controller

Comment: @OrlandoP. i added my code

Comment: @KyawKyawSoe i added my code

Comment: @geeqy do you have  `public function __construct()` method in your `PrintLabelController` class

Comment: @geeqy do you have  `public function __construct()` method in your `PrintLabelController` class

Comment: @geeqy You need to pass [csrf_token](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token) with the ajax call, add this code in your html `{{csrf_field()}}`

Comment: @KyawKyawSoe yes, I have

Comment: @Viney I added it and it didnt work :(

Comment: show your `__construct` method as well

Comment: @KyawKyawSoe I added the code

Comment: that is what you need to looking for, you only allow admin to access this controller, if you are new to Laravel i recommend you to read doc about middleware. add `AdminMiddleware` class code here as well.

Comment: @KyawKyawSoe it worked well when I tried to pass form input data, the problem occured when I tried to access datatable data :( does it have something to do with datatable?

Comment: @geeqy remove `$this->middleware('admin');` and try agin, if `Unauthenticated` error not occur that mean the middleware is problem.

Comment: @KyawKyawSoe i removed it and the error is still the same :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187463/discussion-between-kyaw-kyaw-soe-and-geeqy).

Answer (score 0):

**You might be using artisan serve?**

artisan create some issue when using datatable, take a look at given below link
https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables#php-artisan-serve-bug

If yes, then convert to valet or something else. Thanks!